# How to align more than one DIVs which list of letters to the center

Tags: html, css, alignment

```
<div class="main">
<div class="list">
<br>ABCD
<br>ABC
<br>AB
<br>A
</div>

<div class="list">
<br>ABCD
<br>ABC
<br>AB
<br>A
</div>
</div>
```

i want these DIVs align to the center of the page (like a table with columns which is aligned to the center of the page) and text-align should be left(float left)

how can i do this using css

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: .list{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    }
    .main{
    text-align:center;
    }

Comment: i copied that from another question. but the text is aligned to center which is i don't want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
.main{
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
.main .list{
    text-align:left;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: ok. that works. thank you sir. can you explain what "display:table-cell;" does please?

Answer (score 0):

Add text in p tag and give following css:

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
.main {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6q62rsq9/)